# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't resolve a specific reference correctly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

There are several projects in my solution which are referencing `System.ValueTuple.dll` via nuget. The path to the assembly is defined as the same for all of these projects, but however Visual Studio 2017 is resolving it differently. This leads it to build most of the projects over and over again, although there are no changes.

Here's a sample of how the reference is defined in the project file (again, it's the same for all of the projects):

```
<Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.4.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

And here's the message I get, when Visual Studio wrongly resolves the reference for a project and thus builds it again, whether there are changes or not:

> Project 'XXX' is not up to date. CopyLocal reference source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ValueTuple.dll' is more recent than 'C:\Src\Current.Release\Bin\Debug\System.ValueTuple.dll'.

Why doesn't Visual Studio take the reference I have defined or just fails, if it's not there? It's also showing the wrong path in the references property window.

I can reproduce this behavior on multiple machines. If I check out one of the problematic project files, add a empty line and reload it, it's afterwards resolving the reference correctly. But I mean, there's not really a change I made. If I remap the workspace, the problem comes back.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you marking it as private? its now part of the framework.

Comment: We have to stick to .net 4.6.1 for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2017 doesn't resolve a specific reference correctly

It because:

> **This is due to the injected support for NETStandard 2.0. We inject new assemblies into NET 4.6.1 and later desktop projects in order to
>   add support for netstandard2.0**. We do this in targets now instead of
>   packages because its no longer a requirement to reference a package to
>   build a netstandard library. This injection happens whenever we see a
>   netstandard1.5 or greater library referenced (see dotnet/sdk#1386).

To resolve this issue, you could add binding redirect to those reference.

Check [System.Net.Http v4.2.0.0 being copied/loaded from MSBuild tooling](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But binding redirects are only considered at runtime, right? So these wouldn't help me getting rid of the fact, that my projects are building over and over again, because of the version differences?! Why doesn't Microsoft simply put the same versions of the assemblies on nuget which they are installing on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.  Had similar issues with System.Net.Http.  Lot's of what I am about to say is anecdotal and half-baked in my head.  As I understand, MS started to move away from individual System nupkgs in favour of shipping the DLLs with the framework:

> [We're dead-ending all those packages with the intent that they become part of the framework again in .net 4.7.1. The goal of netstandard2 is to stop the whole package-based portability model because of all of these problems.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23306#issuecomment-322890328)

I think VS 2017 has special case logic:

> [I don't understand what you mean. When you use the latest NuGet package, it contains information INSIDE the package to use the FRAMEWORK DLL instead when you target .NET Framework 4.5+. That is entirely intentional behavior / setting of the NuGet package.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/163040/view.html) (see the comment by Karel at 04:45)

[another comment detailing similar observations as yours](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773)

As an aside, given that you are VS2017, would you consider the `<PackageReference` element instead of `packages.config` file?

Comment: So if I have a project which is referencing an assembly that is targeting .NET Standard 2.0, Visual Studio is going to use newer versions of dependency-assemblies (like `System.ValueTuple`, `System.Collections.Immutable`, etc.), which are not (yet) available on nuget?

Comment: I confess I really don't know, only that MS appears to have some hard to reason about behaviour in this area - especially around the the conversion from 4.6.1 -> 4.7 and I have not found a definititive reference.  In addition, there is lots of stuff written about BindingRedirects that increases the noise level because (ASAIK) they only kick in at runtime, not compile time. Lastly, I think they messed up with some version numbering - nuget package versions that do not match AssemblyVersions that do not match FileVersion and that also increases confusion and counter intuituve BindingRedirects

Comment: I think you're right, they probably messed up some version numbering. Maybe I miss something, but if Microsoft would offer the exact same versions of the assemblies on nuget, which they are installing locally on the computer, would not all the issues disappear?

Answer (score 0):

if you encounter this problem i suggest you to check if both projects use same .Net Framework version.

I fixed same problem that i had with downgrading .Net Framework of my DAL project from 4.5.2 to 4.5.